# Sending Integer to HTTP Server using NameValuePair

Tags: android

I want to send a couple of values to a web server from my Android Client using this `NameValuePair` method:

```
public void postData() {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http:/xxxxxxx");

        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            String amount = paymentAmount.getText().toString();
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("donationAmount", amount));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("paymentMethod", "5"));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately `NameValuePair` is only able to send String, I need to send Integer values as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hi hectichavana If you want to send integer values using name value pair you can try like this

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("gender",Integer.toString(1)));
```

where gender stands for key and 1 will become value of this key.
Hope this help.

Comment: i have five values in spinner with diffrent name like a,b,c,d,e,f i want pass integer values of this string values..how to do it?<string-array name="planets_array">
        <item value="1">a</item>
        <item value="2">b</item>
        <item value="3">c</item>
        <item value="4">d</item>
        <item value="5">e</item>
        <item value="6">f</item>
        
    </string-array>

Comment: @AdityaVyas, ask a new question in a new post.

Comment: Its just matter of getting selected value from spinner. Then you can use Integer.toString() method to convert Integer to String.

@DarylBennett is right your question is not related to this thread.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that the other end of your post request care of your value format the client using and take it all as string. So IMO that's why NameValuePair only take String.
If your data is in numeric format you can always convert it back to String and pair it using NameValuePair

```
new BasicNameValuePair("integer", new Integer().toString(value));
```

is one example that I always use.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies if I am stating the obvious and/or missing the point but the natural solution would appear to  be to convert ints to Strings and then convert back at the server end.  The more complete solution would be to use a different presentation (such as XML) to encode the data.